# Как вытащить значение value у элементов option select и использовать его?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, html-select

При выборе определенного значения должна извлекаться информация из массива, и втавляться в соответствующие ячейки.

Вот пример моего кода:

UPD: изменил код JS для демонстрации кастомного елемнта `select` который я использую.

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item:*/
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();
    });
    b.appendChild(c);
  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);
  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box:*/
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");
  });
}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {
  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div class="left-side">
    <p class="top-txt">вкажіть</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <h4 class="value__name">Вік дитини</h4>
        <div class="form">
          <div class="custom-select">
            <form id="formCalc" name="formCalc" method="get">
              <select id="myCalc">
                <option value="1">1 тиждень</option>
                <option value="2">2 тижні</option>
                <option value="3">3-4 тижні</option>
                <option value="4">2 місяці</option>
                <option value="5">3 місяці</option>
                <option value="6">4 місяці</option>
                <option value="7">5 місяців</option>
                <option value="8">6 місяців</option>
                <option value="9">7 місяців</option>
                <option value="10">8 місяців</option>
                <option value="11">9 місяців</option>
                <option value="12">10 місяців</option>
                <option value="13">11 місяців</option>
                <option value="14">12 місяців</option>
                <option value="15">14 місяців</option>
                <option value="16">16 місяців</option>
                <option value="17">20 місяців</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <p class="top-txt">результат</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="first-wrapp">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість на одне годування</h3>
          <div class="value__wrapper">
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Прокип'ячена<br> вода, мл</h4>
              <div class="value" id="water">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Кількість мірних<br> ложок порошку</h4>
              <div class="value" id="spoons">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab__item">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість<br> годувань<br> на добу</h3>
          <div class="value" id="feedings">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapp">
          <div class="tab__item product">
            <img id="vita1" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/vita1.png" alt="Vita Prim 1">
            <img id="vita2" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita2.png" alt="Vita Prim 2">
            <img id="vita3" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita3.png" alt="Vita Prim 3">
          </div>
          <a href="#" id="calc-btn" class="buy-btn">КУПИТИ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала я сделал `e` глобальной переменной, ибо вы обьявляли слушатель событий для `undefined`, поскольку `e` была локальной переменной для функции `rangeValue`, ее значение "не видно" за пределами тела функции.

Дальше вы назначаете слушатель события изменений значения `select` так:

`e.addEventListener("change", rangeValue);`

где `e` - элемент с которым происходит событие,
`"change"` - название события, `rangeValue` - имя функции, которая срабатывает при событии.

```js
var e = document.querySelector("#myCalc");

var rangeValue = function() {
  var newValue = e.value;
  var feed = document.querySelector('#feedings');
  var water = document.querySelector('#water');
  var spoons = document.querySelector('#spoons');
  var data = [
    [60, 2, 8, 1],
    [90, 3, 7, 1],
    [120, 4, 6, 1],
    [150, 5, 6, 1],
    [180, 6, 5, 1],
    [210, 7, 5, 1],
    [210, 7, 4, 1],
    [210, 7, 4, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [150, 5, 2, 3],
    [180, 6, 2, 3],
    [210, 7, 2, 3]
  ];
  water.innerHTML = data[newValue][0],
    spoons.innerHTML = data[newValue][1],
    feed.innerHTML = data[newValue][2];

  var vita1 = document.getElementById('vita1');
  var vita2 = document.getElementById('vita2');
  var vita3 = document.getElementById('vita3');

  if (newValue == 1) {
    vita1.style.display = "block";
    vita2.style.display = "none";
    vita3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (newValue == 7) {
    vita1.style.display = "none";
    vita2.style.display = "block";
    vita3.style.display = "none";
  } else if (newValue == 13) {
    vita1.style.display = "none";
    vita2.style.display = "none";
    vita3.style.display = "block";
  }
}

e.addEventListener("change", rangeValue);
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div class="left-side">
    <p class="top-txt">вкажіть</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <h4 class="value__name">Вік дитини</h4>
        <div class="form">
          <div class="custom-select">
            <form id="formCalc" name="formCalc" method="get">
              <select id="myCalc">
                <option value="1">1 тиждень</option>
                <option value="2">2 тижні</option>
                <option value="3">3-4 тижні</option>
                <option value="4">2 місяці</option>
                <option value="5">3 місяці</option>
                <option value="6">4 місяці</option>
                <option value="7">5 місяців</option>
                <option value="8">6 місяців</option>
                <option value="9">7 місяців</option>
                <option value="10">8 місяців</option>
                <option value="11">9 місяців</option>
                <option value="12">10 місяців</option>
                <option value="13">11 місяців</option>
                <option value="14">12 місяців</option>
                <option value="15">14 місяців</option>
                <option value="16">16 місяців</option>
                <option value="17">20 місяців</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <p class="top-txt">результат</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="first-wrapp">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість на одне годування</h3>
          <div class="value__wrapper">
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Прокип'ячена<br> вода, мл</h4>
              <div class="value" id="water">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Кількість мірних<br> ложок порошку</h4>
              <div class="value" id="spoons">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab__item">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість<br> годувань<br> на добу</h3>
          <div class="value" id="feedings">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapp">
          <div class="tab__item product">
            <img id="vita1" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/vita1.png" alt="Vita Prim 1">
            <img id="vita2" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita2.png" alt="Vita Prim 2">
            <img id="vita3" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita3.png" alt="Vita Prim 3">
          </div>
          <a href="#" id="calc-btn" class="buy-btn">КУПИТИ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я изменил, согласно Вашему примеру, и оно работает, но работает в сферическом вакууме, так как идентичный код в проекте (интернет-магазин wordpress) не работает. Пока не разобрался почему, но спасибо большое!

Comment: @ArtemKulikov вы можете скинуть сюда ошибки, если я сталкивался с таким, то готов помочь вам разобраться

Comment: Ошибки никакой не выдаёт, просто браузер, почему-то, не заходит в функцию rangeValue, например, если вставить console.log() до или после функции - все работает, но в самой функции он не срабатывает, из этого я делаю вывод, что браузер просто не заходит внутрь функции. А вот почему - загадка для меня. Возможно какойто плагин WP перекрывает событие "change", есть у меня такая догадка

Comment: @ArtemKulikov проверьте в devtools, какая функция срабатывает при событии `change`, в Chrome это можно найти во вкладке elements -> выбираете ваш `select`, переходите в Event Listeners, там увидите в меню change какая строчка кода в каком файле отрабатывает при событии.

Comment: посмотрел, в `change` пишет `select#myCalc` ,и еще много инфы, включая `name: "rangeValue"` . Пока ничего не понятно, но очень интересно. Какую конкретно информацию я могу Вам предоставить, что бы Вам было проще разобраться? Спасибо!

Comment: Еще я подумал, что прблема может быть в том, что я использую кастомный `select` и в первую очередь надо взаимодействовать с его кодом. Сейчас я обновлю код в самом вопросе, и добавлю туда код для кастомного `select`

Answer (score 0):

Ниже пример как считать данные - дальше сможете подставить как нужно, полагаю

```js
let data = [
    [60, 2, 8, 1],
    [90, 3, 7, 1],
    [120, 4, 6, 1],
    [150, 5, 6, 1],
    [180, 6, 5, 1],
    [210, 7, 5, 1],
    [210, 7, 4, 1],
    [210, 7, 4, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [210, 7, 3, 2],
    [150, 5, 2, 3],
    [180, 6, 2, 3],
    [210, 7, 2, 3]
  ];

let select_element = document.getElementById('myCalc');

select_element.addEventListener('change', function() {

console.log( data [this.value] );

} );
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div class="left-side">
    <p class="top-txt">вкажіть</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <h4 class="value__name">Вік дитини</h4>
        <div class="form">
          <div class="custom-select">
            <form id="formCalc" name="formCalc" method="get">
              <select id="myCalc">
                <option value="1">1 тиждень</option>
                <option value="2">2 тижні</option>
                <option value="3">3-4 тижні</option>
                <option value="4">2 місяці</option>
                <option value="5">3 місяці</option>
                <option value="6">4 місяці</option>
                <option value="7">5 місяців</option>
                <option value="8">6 місяців</option>
                <option value="9">7 місяців</option>
                <option value="10">8 місяців</option>
                <option value="11">9 місяців</option>
                <option value="12">10 місяців</option>
                <option value="13">11 місяців</option>
                <option value="14">12 місяців</option>
                <option value="15">14 місяців</option>
                <option value="16">16 місяців</option>
                <option value="17">20 місяців</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <p class="top-txt">результат</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="first-wrapp">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість на одне годування</h3>
          <div class="value__wrapper">
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Прокип'ячена<br> вода, мл</h4>
              <div class="value" id="water">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Кількість мірних<br> ложок порошку</h4>
              <div class="value" id="spoons">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab__item">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість<br> годувань<br> на добу</h3>
          <div class="value" id="feedings">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapp">
          <div class="tab__item product">
            <img id="vita1" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/vita1.png" alt="Vita Prim 1">
            <img id="vita2" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita2.png" alt="Vita Prim 2">
            <img id="vita3" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita3.png" alt="Vita Prim 3">
          </div>
          <a href="#" id="calc-btn" class="buy-btn">КУПИТИ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, теперь всё работает как надо, всем спасибо!

```js
var x, i, j, l, ll, selElmnt, a, b, c;
/*look for any elements with the class "custom-select":*/
x = document.getElementsByClassName("custom-select");
l = x.length;
for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  selElmnt = x[i].getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
  ll = selElmnt.length;
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will act as the selected item:*/
  a = document.createElement("DIV");
  a.setAttribute("class", "select-selected");
  a.setAttribute("id", "select-selected");
  a.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[selElmnt.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
  x[i].appendChild(a);
  /*for each element, create a new DIV that will contain the option list:*/
  b = document.createElement("DIV");
  b.setAttribute("class", "select-items select-hide");
  for (j = 1; j < ll; j++) {
    /*for each option in the original select element,
    create a new DIV that will act as an option item:*/
    c = document.createElement("DIV");
    c.innerHTML = selElmnt.options[j].innerHTML;
    c.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      /*when an item is clicked, update the original select box,
      and the selected item:*/
      var y, i, k, s, h, sl, yl;
      s = this.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
      sl = s.length;
      h = this.parentNode.previousSibling;
      for (i = 0; i < sl; i++) {
        if (s.options[i].innerHTML == this.innerHTML) {
          s.selectedIndex = i;
          h.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
          y = this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("same-as-selected");
          yl = y.length;
          for (k = 0; k < yl; k++) {
            y[k].removeAttribute("class");
          }
          this.setAttribute("class", "same-as-selected");
          break;
        }
      }
      h.click();

    });
    b.appendChild(c);

  }
  x[i].appendChild(b);

  a.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

    /*when the select box is clicked, close any other select boxes,
    and open/close the current select box:*/
    e.stopPropagation();
    closeAllSelect(this);
    this.nextSibling.classList.toggle("select-hide");
    this.classList.toggle("select-arrow-active");


    var newValue = document.querySelector("#myCalc").value;
    // alert(newValue);
    var feed = document.querySelector('#feedings');
    var water = document.querySelector('#water');
    var spoons = document.querySelector('#spoons');
    var data = [
      [60, 2, 8],
      [90, 3, 7],
      [120, 4, 6],
      [150, 5, 6],
      [180, 6, 5],
      [210, 7, 5],
      [210, 7, 4],
      [210, 7, 4],
      [210, 7, 3],
      [210, 7, 3],
      [210, 7, 3],
      [210, 7, 3],
      [210, 7, 3],
      [210, 7, 3],
      [150, 5, 2],
      [180, 6, 2],
      [210, 7, 2]
    ];

    water.innerHTML = data[newValue][0],
      spoons.innerHTML = data[newValue][1],
      feed.innerHTML = data[newValue][2];

    var vita1 = document.getElementById('vita1');
    var vita2 = document.getElementById('vita2');
    var vita3 = document.getElementById('vita3');

    if (newValue <= 7) {
      vita1.style.display = "block";
      vita2.style.display = "none";
      vita3.style.display = "none";
    } else if (newValue <= 13) {
      vita1.style.display = "none";
      vita2.style.display = "block";
      vita3.style.display = "none";
    } else if (newValue <= 17) {
      vita1.style.display = "none";
      vita2.style.display = "none";
      vita3.style.display = "block";
    }
  });

}

function closeAllSelect(elmnt) {

  /*a function that will close all select boxes in the document,
  except the current select box:*/
  var x, y, i, xl, yl, arrNo = [];
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("select-items");
  y = document.getElementsByClassName("select-selected");
  xl = x.length;
  yl = y.length;
  for (i = 0; i < yl; i++) {
    if (elmnt == y[i]) {
      arrNo.push(i)
    } else {
      y[i].classList.remove("select-arrow-active");
    }
  }
  for (i = 0; i < xl; i++) {
    if (arrNo.indexOf(i)) {
      x[i].classList.add("select-hide");
    }
  }
}
/*if the user clicks anywhere outside the select box,
then close all select boxes:*/
document.addEventListener("click", closeAllSelect);
```

```css
.custom-select {
  position: relative;
  width: 130px;
}

.custom-select select {
  display: none;
}

.select-selected {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.select-selected:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 20px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 6px solid #00b0ca6b;
  border-color: #00b0ca transparent transparent transparent;
}

.select-selected.select-arrow-active:after {
  border-color: transparent transparent #00b0ca transparent;
  top: 13px;
}

.select-items div,
.select-selected {
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: transparent transparent rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  color: #00b0ca;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.select-items:nth-child(1),
.select-selected {
  border: 3px solid #00b0ca6b;
  border-radius: 17px
}

.select-items {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}

.select-hide {
  display: none;
}

.select-items div:hover,
.same-as-selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div class="left-side">
    <p class="top-txt">вкажіть</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <h4 class="value__name">Вік дитини</h4>
        <div class="form">
          <div class="custom-select">
            <form id="formCalc" name="formCalc" method="get">
              <select id="myCalc">
                <option value="1">1 тиждень</option>
                <option value="2">2 тижні</option>
                <option value="3">3-4 тижні</option>
                <option value="4">2 місяці</option>
                <option value="5">3 місяці</option>
                <option value="6">4 місяці</option>
                <option value="7">5 місяців</option>
                <option value="8">6 місяців</option>
                <option value="9">7 місяців</option>
                <option value="10">8 місяців</option>
                <option value="11">9 місяців</option>
                <option value="12">10 місяців</option>
                <option value="13">11 місяців</option>
                <option value="14">12 місяців</option>
                <option value="15">14 місяців</option>
                <option value="16">16 місяців</option>
                <option value="17">20 місяців</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-side">
    <p class="top-txt">результат</p>
    <div class="tab-wrapper">
      <div class="tab">
        <div class="first-wrapp">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість на одне годування</h3>
          <div class="value__wrapper">
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Прокип'ячена<br> вода, мл</h4>
              <div class="value" id="water">0</div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab__item">
              <h4 class="value__subname">Кількість мірних<br> ложок порошку</h4>
              <div class="value" id="spoons">0</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab__item">
          <h3 class="value__name">Кількість<br> годувань<br> на добу</h3>
          <div class="value" id="feedings">0</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapp">
          <div class="tab__item product">
            <img id="vita1" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/vita1.png" alt="Vita Prim 1">
            <img id="vita2" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita2.png" alt="Vita Prim 2">
            <img id="vita3" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/vita3.png" alt="Vita Prim 3">
          </div>
          <a href="#" id="calc-btn" class="buy-btn">КУПИТИ</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```